# anova1 generating error : MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Below is my code for a function is fits a series of data points if the anova1 p value<0.05. However, despite the number of rows size(y,1) being equal to the length in group, I am still getting the error message in MATLAB that "X and GROUP must have the same length". What could be going wrong here?

```
function [a,b,c,d] = fit_arm_nerve(filename)

data = load(filename,'-ascii');

x = data(1,:);
y = data(2:end,:);
Num_Reps = size(y,1);  
length(y)
G = [repmat(1:length(y),Num_Reps,1)];
length(G)
anova_p = anova1(y,G,'off');

if anova_p<0.05
   [a,b,c,d] = gaussfit(x,y); 
else
    a = NaN;
    b = NaN;
    c = NaN;
    d = NaN;
end
end
```

Comment: does it crash in gaussfit(x,y) ?

Comment: no, it does'nt even get there, it stops at anova1

Comment: Can you add a minimum example of data to your question for better understanding of your porblem?

Answer (score 0):

Try `anova1(y(:),G(:),'off')` and see whether it passes anova1. If it works, maybe the *length* is the same but the *size* is different, so check it.